# Loading dependencies from node_modules in Angular 2 for hosted apps

Tags: npm, angular, node-modules

I wanted start with the new Angular 2 but I can't grasp how npm is used in the official (and several other) tutorials. For me the `node_modules` directory is mainly used for development but in `index.html` the needed script files are mostly included from this location:

```
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
```

When hosting the app on your own machine, there seems to be no problem because everything would be present due to `npm install`. But if I want to host my app somewhere else (e.g. as a Github Page) I generally don't have `node_modules` as it would be excluded in `.gitignore`.

One way would be to load the dependencies via some CDN but is there a better solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as you know `node_modules` are mainly used for development purpose, you dont need them in your repo while hosting your code.

You can follow two approaches here.

1. Deploy as it is. Just that - `no minification, concatenation, name mangling etc.copy all your node_modules,Transpile all your ts project, copy all your resulting js/css/... to the hosting server` and you can host your app.
2. second approach will be the recommended one.Deploy using special bundling tools. Like `webpack or systemjs builder`.basically these builder will make a bundle of your application, and you can just deploy that bundle on the server.

For more reference, I have provided links of sample apps:

1. [Webpack Starter](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter)
2. [SystemJS builder](https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed)

Hoe this helps.